# Uninitialized value in concatenation

Tags: perl

I have the "uninitialized value in concatenation" error that is thoroughly discussed in this forum, and generally refers to an undefined variable.

However, as a newbie, I'm short on "why" the problem exists in the code below.

The error refers to the variables $sb and $filesize.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!!

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;

#The directory where you store the filings
my $dir="/Volumes/EDGAR1/Edgar/Edgar2/10K/2009";    

opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;  

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

# Use a regular expression to ignore files beginning with a period
    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);

#my $form_type=substr($line,62,12);
#my $cik=substr($line,74,10);
#my $file_date=substr($line,86,10);

#Note that for file date, we need to get rid of 
#the - with the following regular expression.
#month-day-year and some years there is not.
#This regular expression 
#my $file_date=~s/\-//g;
my $filesize = -s "$file";
my $sb = (stat($file))[7];

print "$file,$sb,$filesize\n";

}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using the [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) module. This module implements a `stat` functionality that overrides Perl's built-in. And it returns an object instead of a list. So this:

```
my $sb = (stat($file))[7];
```

Causes `$sb` to be undefined, because there is only 1 object in the list. What you do is use the modules functions instead:

```
my $sb = stat($file)->size();
```